# How to plot x+y in MatLab using ezplot

Tags: matlab

I tried `ezplot` in MatLab

```
ezplot('1.395x-1.935y+16.65')
```

but got the following errors:

```
Error using inlineeval (line 14)
Error in inline expression ==> 1.395x-1.935y+16.65
Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.
Error in inline/feval (line 33)
    INLINE_OUT_ = inlineeval(INLINE_INPUTS_, INLINE_OBJ_.inputExpr, INLINE_OBJ_.expr);
Error in ezplotfeval (line 51)
    z = feval(f,x(1));
Error in ezplot>ezplot1 (line 468)
    [y, f, loopflag] = ezplotfeval(f, x);

Error in ezplot (line 144)
    [hp, cax] = ezplot1(cax, f{1}, vars, labels, args{:});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to put a multiplication sign (`*`). Try this:

```
ezplot('1.395*x-1.935*y+16.65')
```